# How to process/eval $ajax response as html/javascript when loading into a jquery dialog in MVC 3?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I have index page with a list of users and an edit link. When I click this link I wold like to open a jquery dialog to edit and then save.

I am doing an ajax get on another view and loading the return data into a div. The return data is html and javascript both. The return is just text essentially. I need the javascript in the return to be executed, sort of like running eval. Is this possible or is there a better way to do it? I guess I could just open it in a window.open or an iframe. However I was wondering if jquery dialog or any other model dialog solution is possible? Is there a recommended way?

```
   $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
            url:  "/User/Edit/" + user.Id,
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'html',
            error: function (xmlHttpRequest) {                  
                $("#edit-dialog").html(xmlHttpRequest.responseText);
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $("#edit-dialog").html(data);                   
                $("#edit-dialog").dialog("open");
            }             
        });
```

The page edit is more than just a simple form - it has reasonable amount of javascript and ui candy. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inline JavaScript should be executed as soon as the browser renders it. I think the problem is you are using `document.ready` to initialize, but this will never fire if you add the HTML after initial page rendering. 2nd, all JavaScript has to come after HTML, because JS will not find HTML elements.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Maybe I was looking at it for too long. It makes perfect sense. The page I was loading via the ajax call had its javascript wrapped in a document.ready. All I had to do was call it directly by removing the $(function(){}); it was wrapped in.